# Specify what CAS should return after authentication

Tags: cas

I have installed CAS6.4. Installed CAS Management as well.
I am able to authenticate using LDAP and its returns username.
I want to get userid as well from LDAP .
can someone specify how can i get

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, add below property in cas.properties

cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeList=fieldname